# Can my Thinkpad w550s run elementary os with no problem?

Tags: nvidia, lenovo, thinkpad

I have a lenovo thinkpad w550s with the following specs:
-Intel core i7 5500U
-8gb ram
-256 ssd
-nvidia QuadroK620m
- full hd screen

And I wanted to uninstall the windows and install the elementary 0.4 Loki and use it as my only operating system.

Does the elementary 0.4 Loki run well and without problems on my pc?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's likely a good sign that Ubuntu has [certified](https://certification.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201412-16338/) the Lenovo w550s, and Lenovo's have alsways worked flawlessly for me (currently on a t450), but it's always a good idea to test a number your usual tasks from a live USB.

Answer (score 0):

When you boot up the elementary 0.4 Loki you will see 2 options on the left Try elementary and on the right the Install elementary. I would suggest to select the Try elemetary options and test everything first and configure everything you can work with it. If you're thinking this works you can install elemetary afterwards.